# visualization of compressed (deflated, gzipped) content structures

Tags: zip, gzip, visualization, compression

I have some ideas I would like to experiment with relating to data compression, but am finding it difficult to decipher some parts of how the standard are applied "in real life". I would like to look at some sample compressed files to observe how the the blocks are arranged and the huffman tree(s) are structured.

Are there any tools in existence which can help visualize this for a given compressed file (zip/gzip/deflate etc)? I'm picturing something like a tree view or some form of graph visualizer.

Comment: I think I see a tumbleweed ;)

Comment: wow, no compression gurus around eh?

Comment: I also would like some visualization tools. Tell us if you ever find any useful ones, OK?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451997/zlib-gzip-interpreter

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in this (if you are still interested that is :-P)

http://jvns.ca/blog/2013/10/24/day-16-gzip-plus-poetry-equals-awesome/

Answer (score 3):

I made a ["entropy image" tool](http://david.carybros.com/program/image_processing/entropy_image.m).

The entropy_image tool replaces each pixel
with the (estimated) number of bits
necessary to encode that pixel using range coding or Huffman compression.

I hope this isn't the only compression visualization tool in the world.